# Why does command on GCE work on console terminal but not as a Cron job

Tags: cron, google-compute-engine

I can run this command on my instance using web console;

> gsutil rsync -d -r /my-path gs://my-bucket

But when I try on my remote ssh terminal I get this error;

```
root@instance-2: gsutil rsync -d -r /my-path gs://my-bucket
Building synchronization state...
INFO 0923 12:48:48.572446 multistore_file.py] Error decoding credential, skipping
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/multistore_file.py", line 381, in _refresh_data_cache
        (key, credential) = self._decode_credential_from_json(cred_entry)
      File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/multistore_file.py", line 400, in _decode_credential_from_json
        credential = Credentials.new_from_json(json.dumps(cred_entry['credential']))
      File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py", line 292, in new_from_json
        return from_json(s)
      File "/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/platform/gsutil/third_party/apitools/apitools/base/py/credentials_lib.py", line 356, in from_json
        data['token_expiry'], oauth2client.client.EXPIRY_FORMAT)
    TypeError: must be string, not None
    Caught non-retryable exception while listing gs://my-bucket/: Could not reach metadata service: Not Found
    At source listing 10000...
    At source listing 20000...
    At source listing 30000...
    At source listing 40000...
    CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the Service Account assigned to the instance has IAM permissions that will allow it to write to the bucket.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by switching the user to the default CGE one that is created when the project is created. Root on the VM does not have privileges to run gsutil commands it seems.